# application making http requests should go through proxy server

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, java

I have a java app running on an ubuntu server. It makes https requests to a specific other host (say example.com), but it needs to routed through a proxy server, such that it appears that the https request comes from a different IP than the IP the application is running on.

Is it possible to just configure that one application to route all its http requests and responses through a proxy server of choice?

I am unfamiliar with the whole landscape so i am a bit confused as to what 'ingredients' I need for such a setup. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to just configure that one application to route all its http requests and responses through a proxy server of choice?

Absolutely, but that application needs to be capable of being configured in that way.  Many HTTP-sending applications have a configuration option to set up a proxy server that will be used; many others don't have a proxy configuration implemented.

Picking one off my screen right now that happens to also be a java server application, VMware Update Manager, has a configuration section for it:

[image: proxy settings]

If how to configure this isn't in the documentation of the software you're using, you'll need to yell at the vendor of the application - they need to support it for it to work.

Comment: thanks, okay luckily i'm the author of that application, so I will look into that how to achieve that.